# How to make sure managed package trigger can be executed by everybody

Tags: apex, trigger

Our managed package adds a trigger on `Contact` and `Lead` insert/update. After an organization installs the package, the trigger is executed whenever a `Contact` or `Lead` is inserted/updated, even if the user does not have a license to use the managed package. Following apex development best practices, I created a separate class that holds the trigger's logic. How can I make sure this class can always be executed since sometimes the trigger could be executed by some users who do not have a license?

Answer (score 0):

I believe those triggers are always going to run and you don't have to make any other adjustments.

If you're concerned about custom fields and visibility / field level security (FLS) issues that might prevent your triggers from doing what they need to do, consider either:

1. Applying a managed package permission set to all org users that has all the FLS / CRUD permissions set for your custom fields / custom objects within the package.
2. You could add `without sharing` to the Apex class definition.

Option 2 is definitely less of a best practice than option 1 and should be used with great caution, especially if this managed package is trying to make it's way to the AppExchange and has to pass Security Review

Comment: Yeah I noticed that for some reason I don't seem to have permission problems with those triggers, maybe it is because they are run in a permission-less environment or something like that? I do already apply a permission set to all users